# Fetching static files failed with 404 in nginx

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I'm now deploying an django app with nginx and gunicorn on ubuntu 12.

And I configure the nginx virtual host file as below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/gunicorn.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/django/ecerp/erp/static/;
    }

}
```

I can request the django well, but when request a static file, it response with 404 status.

I'm sure the root path of static file is correct.

Can anyone help?

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block. http://nginx.org/r/root

Comment: I would also make sure your nginx user has permissions to access the directory. Good luck

Comment: @pztrick not permission problem. I changed it to be 777. And now returning 404 but not 403.

Comment: My own configuration uses the `alias` directive instead of `root`. I also place the static and media paths BEFORE the naked `location /`. Maybe it is routing to `location /` match first?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Wow! Your solution helps! I found that if I request `http://example.com/static/somepath`, it maps to `/var/www/django/ecerp/erp/static/static/`! So when I remove the trailing `static/`, I works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @pztrick, not the order problem, I've solve that, a redundant `static/` should be removed!

Comment: The order was my problem! Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You should use `alias` instead of `root`. `root` appends the trailing URL parts to your local path (e.g. http://test.ndd/trailing/part, it will add /trailing/part to your local path). Instead of that, `alias` does exactly what you want: when http://test.ndd/static/ is requested, /static is mapped to your alias exactly, without appending static again.

For example:

```
location /static {
    alias /var/www/django/ecerp/erp/static/;
}
```

And if file `/var/www/django/ecerp/erp/static/foo.html` exists then going to `/static/foo.html` will return its contents.

Comment: After hours of searching, I found this working for me.

Answer (score 19):

**TL;DR - you should check your files permissions**

Stumbled upon this question and I was already using `alias` instead of root, so while the existing answer was up to the point, the following could be useful to others.

In my case, the solution to the same symptoms turned out to be the files in `static/` having `root` as owner.

A simple `chown www-data:www-data .` solved the problem, and no more `404`.

Comment: I also tried this with chmod. Which permission does nginx actually need on the file? Read-Only seems not enough. Full access seems overkill.

Comment: @ST-DDT it's not a good idea to access `root` files from Nginx, whatever permissions they might have. Using `chown` is a much better choice here.

Comment: here is a sample command:

sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/acd.com/service/uploads/