# django static files not appearing with virtual environment

Tags: django, static, http-status-code-404, virtualenv

So I'm trying to push my website into production, but I have encountered a problem while in the virtual environment, where my static files are not being found (404 errors).

In the settings.py file, I have `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')`.

In the file /etc/nginx/sites-available/django, I have modified the static files location, to look like this:

```
location /static {
     alias /home/user/myproject/static;
}
```

In the directory /home/user/myproject, I have another directory called `static`, and inside are several directories holding the actual static files.

i.e. /home/user/myproject/static/shopApp/shop_app.css

or

i.e. /home/user/myproject/static/officeApp/office_app.css

What I am trying to see is if any of my configurations are set up badly. I am very new to django and web development, so I would appreciate any of your help!

EDIT: After doing some research I think I have the same problem as the guy from stackoverflow in this link: [Fetching static files failed with 404 in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237936/fetching-static-files-failed-with-404-in-nginx).

I think the second answer might solve my issue but I don't know where to apply the command `chown www-data:www-data .`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that the problem was with my settings.py file.

Specifically, when your still using the django development server with your virtual environment (0.0.0.0:8000), you should have **DEBUG** set to **True**, so that it can serve your static files.

Remember! This is only if your using a django **development** server. For **production**, it should be set to **False**.

I got this information from this django article: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

STATIC_ROOT only for prod, static folder for you app or project. PROD static != project static. For example you have 10 apps, like django admin. Without STATIC_ROOT and collectstatic command, you need point to each static folder in each app.
For example 
`location /static/admin {
     alias /home/user/myproject/env../admin/static;
}
location /static/someapp {
alias /home/user/myproject/someapp/static;
}`
 But Django does a lot of work for you. You need to point to folder, which collects all static from all apps. For example STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_remote/') and run collectstatic
`location /static {
     alias /home/user/myproject/static_root;
}`

Comment: Hello, I am confused as to what folder I need to to point to, so that django collects all static. Also, do you mean that for the alias of the static location, I should replace it with **static_root**? Is that the solution or do I still need to point to each static folder in each app?

Comment: you need replace to any name but not static

Comment: So if I make the alias `/home/user/myproject/static_root;`, do I have to name the directory containing other folders that have the static files **static_root**? Why is this different from my original case with **static**? Thank you for your quick replies.

Comment: No , STATIC_ROOT const used only for production. Look at django code. Django using finders. When you need static files to put in one location, finders try to find **static** folder in all apps, which declared in INSTALLED_APPS. ie you create app and create folder whith name **static**. When you run django in debug mode (django has internal sever) finders automatically get content of static files, but in production mode, nginx can't by self find this files, so you need point to folders in each app or call collectstatic, which collects all files in one folder.

Comment: so STATIC_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'any name what you want/')
but in your apps, for example blog, forum, chat : blog/static, forum/static/, chat/static
and dont forget, we copy in one location - you need different subfolders or different names of static files to prevent rewrite. For example blog/static/blog/css[img, js] or
forum/static/forum/css  forum/static/forum/js

Comment: After following your instructions, I still get 404 errors for my static files. I edited my question with some more information regarding my problem.